# Java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Tags: java, bluej, operands

Every time I try to start my code I have always the same error:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "x"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at Variable.<init>(Variable.java:17)
 at Main.main(Main.java:4)`
```

I put also my code. Can you help me to understand what was wrong?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(final String[] args) { 
    final Node expression =
      new Plus(
        new Minus(
          new Plus(
            new Variable("x"),
            new Literal(2)
          ),
          new Variable("y")
        ),
        new Minus(
          new Literal(4),
          new Variable("z")
        )
      );
    // an interpreter would just evaluate the expression:
    System.out.println("Expression is: " + expression);

    // a compiler would compile the expression into a program
    System.out.println("Compiling expression...");
    final Program program = new Program();
    expression.generateCode(program);
    System.out.println("Resulting program:\n"+program);

    // and, later, that program can then be executed after the variables have been assigned
    // First assignment of variables
    VariableSpace variables = new VariableSpace();
    variables.store("x", 5);
    variables.store("y", 7);   
    variables.store("z", 1);
    System.out.println("For x = 5, y = 7 and z = 1 the program executes and returns:");
    int resultOfExecution = program.execute(variables);
    System.out.println(resultOfExecution);

    // Second assignment of variables
    variables.store("x", 11);
    variables.store("y", 3);
    variables.store("z", 2);
    System.out.println("For x = 11, y = 3, and z = 2 the program executes and returns:");
    resultOfExecution = program.execute(variables);
    System.out.println(resultOfExecution);        
}

public class Variable extends Node
{
    String variable;
    int value;
    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Variable
    */
    public Variable(final String variable)
    {
        this.variable = variable;
        int value = Integer.parseInt(variable);
    }

    public void generateCode(final Program program) {
        program.append(new ILOAD(value));
    }

    /**
     * Return a int representing this expression
     * (e.g., new Literal(19).toint() is "19").
     */
      public String toString() {
      return "" + value;
      }
    }

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A Node in an abstract syntax tree (AST)
* for a very simple expression language.
* The language only supports the following subtypes of Nodes:
* <ul>
* <li>integer values (class Literal)
* <li>integer variables (class Variables)
* <li>the integer + operator (class Plus)
* <li>the integer - operator (class Minus)
* </ul>
* It does not support types other than integers.
*/

public class Node {

/**
 * Compile this AST into an IJVM program:
 * Append instructions to the given Program
 * such that the instructions, when executed
 * produce the same value 
 * as is produced by a call to evaluate(). 
 */
public void generateCode(Program program) {
}

/**
 * Generate a string-representation of the subtree.
 * When you implement this method in subclasses,
 * where possible use recursive calls to left.toString() and
 * to right.toString() to do this.
 */
public String toString() {
    return null;
}

}

public class ILOAD extends Instruction
{
private final int value;

public ILOAD(final int value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public void execute(Storage storage) {
    storage.getStack().push(value);
}

/**
 * Produce a human-readable String-representation of this instruction.
 */
public String toString() {
    return "ILAOAD " + value;  
}

}

import java.util.*;

/**
* A space that stores the variables during the execution of the IJVM/Java bytecode.
*/
public class VariableSpace {

private HashMap<String, Integer> value;

public VariableSpace() {
    value = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

public void store(String name, int value) {
    this.value.put(name, value);   
}

public int load(String name) {
    return value.get(name);
}

}
```

The problem I have is in the class Variable where I try to convert a String in an Integer because class ILOAD need an integer. I'm so sorry if the code i too long, but the classes are linked each other. Hope you will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't  post the code of the class `VariableSpace` , so I assume its a kinde of a map which holds the value for each variable.

In the constructor of Variable you are trying to parse the variable `x` name as an int which fails with a `NumberFormatException` because x does not represent an integer.

What you want to do is actually retrieve the value from `VariablStore`

```
int value = variablStore.getValue(variable);
```

For that the instance of `VariablStore` needs to be accessible from the class `Varaiable`. At the moment it is local in the main method.

**EDIT**

After seeing the whole code, here are the changes you need:

ILOAD class

```
/**
 * ILOAD instruction gets the valiable name for later retrieving of the value
 * in {@link ILOAD#execute(Storage)}
 * 
 * @param variable
 */
public ILOAD(final String variable)
{
    this.variable = variable;
}


/**
 * retrieve the variable value using its name from the storage and push it on the stack
 */
public void execute(Storage storage) {
    storage.getStack().push(storage.getVariables().load(variable));
}
```

Variable class

```
String variable;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Variable
 */
public Variable(final String variable)
{
    this.variable = variable;
}

/**
 * Create a ILOAD instance and pass it the variable name. 
 * ILOAD extends Instruction and overrides the method {@link Instruction#execute(Storage)}
 * which get as argument the {@link Storage} class and from which the value can be retrieved.  
 */
public void generateCode(final Program program) {
    program.append(new ILOAD(variable));
}
```

Comment: So so sorry, I knew I forget something I will upload in the original code

Comment: @AnnamariaAccardo, so your method is named `load` ... see my edit

Comment: Ok the problem is that BlueJ can't find varibleStore method

Comment: and also int cannot be dereferenced; the error is get. I try to add the method "load" after the constructor Variable but I didn't put int value = variablStore.load(variable);

Comment: @AnnamariaAccardo I have edited my answer to make `VariableStore` static, you can access it by the class name, otherwise if you want to keep accessing it by instance then you have to pass a reference to it to each instance of the class `Variable` you create.

Comment: Ok I tried to do it but I have the same error as I said before "cannot find the symbol VariableStore"

Comment: @AnnamariaAccardo did you import it in the `Variable` class: `import VariableScore;`?

Comment: No possible to import VariableScore (VariableStore neither)

Comment: What error message do you exactly get? did you include the package name in the import directive?

Comment: I include the import in the first line of class Variable. The code I put was java.util.VariableScore; (also VariableStore). The error message was "cannot find symbol - class VariableStore (VariableScore)

Comment: `import java.util.VariableScore;` will not work because your class is not in the package `java.util`, From what I see you are using the default package, i.e. no package at all. so `import VariableScore;` should work, put it in the line right after `import java.util.*;`

Comment: ok so I can import all the packages in Java. Yeah I didn't work with all packages. Just with some util but the error is the same also if I put the *. I think that maybe the mistake is easily but I can't see it. If your have an e-mail I can sent you the project so it's easily. Here is mine, you can contact me only as professional consult and them stop any conversations if there are problems

Comment: accara@usi.ch. No problems for me

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [docs for Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

According to those `Integer.parseInt(String s)`

> Throws 
>   NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable
>   integer

Parsing an integer from a String that contains none is exactly what you are trying to do in this constructor for class `Variable`...

```
public Variable(final String variable)
{
    this.variable = variable;
    int value = Integer.parseInt(variable);
}
```

...when you invoke it like this.

```
new Variable("x")
```

Comment: As I said to your "colleague", it is absolutely correct what you are saying but the only classes I can change are ILOAD and Variable. I tried to say that variable has to be an int but then BlueJ says to me that String is required. I try to change in String and says that int are required.

Comment: The basic problem is generateCode. In fact the generateCode(Program) methods create and add Instruction objects to the given Program. Maybe I have to change something there?

Answer (score 1):

the error message is clear

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "x"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
```

you're trying to convert a string "x" into an Integer in the parseInt() method, probably at this part

```
public Variable(final String variable)
    {
        this.variable = variable;
        int value = Integer.parseInt(variable);
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. The only classes I can change are ILOAD and Variable. I tried to say that variable has to be an int but then BlueJ says to me that String is required. I try to change in String and says that int are required.

Comment: The basic problem is generateCode. In fact the generateCode(Program) methods create and add Instruction objects to the given Program. Maybe I have to change something there?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do, but are you trying to evaluate the variable? Like assigning an int value to a variable?

Comment: It seems to me that your Variable constructor should have both the variable name (String) and the variable value (int) as parameters.

Comment: I'm trying to create the ILOAD class that load your variable x in the stack; it's the same process that memory do. The output of the function, when I call main should be:

    `Resulting program:
    ILOAD x
    BIPUSH 2
    IADD
    ILOAD y
    ISUB
    BIPUSH 4
    ILOAD z
    ISUB
    IADD
    For x = 5, y = 7 and z = 1 the program executes and returns:
    3
    For x = 11, y = 3, and z = 2 the program executes and returns:
    12 `
Sorry I tried to intent but it's impossible I think

Comment: oh, I remember I've done something like that in college many years ago [1996] :-) in this case, it's important to understand the processor structures and try to simulate them. OMG I am so old! :-)

Comment: Yes I understand the process but I don't know what is the problem. The class Main calls Variable and pass a string but then ILOAD need an int to push it in the stack and calculate

Comment: well, it seems that you have two steps to solve here. The first one is to create the necessary code to represent your AST. From your AST, you can generate your assembly program. The second step is to interpret your program, emulating what a real processor would do.

Comment: Yes the problem is that the only classes I can modify are Variable and ILOAD. I thing that ILOAD is quite right but the huge problem is in Varible

Comment: I am not sure, but my feeling is that you must not assign the Variable value in the constructor. In the way you're doing, variables and literals (i think) are supposed to be immutable, and the result of the arithmetic operations should go to the VariableSpace structure, maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your consideration

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse "x" into an Integer. Do you think possible? Definitely No! That's why it throws NumberFormatException

Read about [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)